# Tethered and Tied

Tags: verbs, differences

I don't see any difference between those two verbs, meaning to be tethered and to be tied.
Can you explain me the nuance ?

thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tethered should only mean that there is a cord or rope holding the object to a place such as a post. This is the proper use of a tether. A balloon could be tethered to the ground and trying to float away.

To be tied could also mean using a tether but generally means fastened or secured in a more definite way. A boat is tied fast [meaning tied securely] to the dock to keep it from drifting away.

Comment: You are going to need to reference the sources you use to write a proper answer. https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer..

Comment: @J.Taylor Just FYI, when an expert writes from their own expertise there won't necessarily be any external sources relied on. The help page you referenced, and the one on referencing (https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) don't say that you must use external sources. They say that you must properly credit external sources when you use them.